# woocommerce related product title length

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, title

Can't believe there is no standard workaround to limit product title for the related product section. So far, I managed to limit product title for all other pages by using Woo Title Limit plugin.

By using this plugin, I can make the related product to limit its title by inserting limit to single product page, but then it will affect the single product title also. So, I think the best way is to add it manually for the related product.

I think this is the standardize code to limit product title character.

```
    if ( strlen( $title ) > 60) { // Kicks in if the product title is longer than 60 characters 
  return substr( $title, 0, 60 ) . '...'; // Shortens it to 60 characters and adds ellipsis at the end
} else {
  return $title; // If the title isn't longer than 60 characters, it will be returned in its full length without the ellipsis
}
```

Now, the problem is where can I apply this code? I can't just simply paste this code inside the related.php page right? Mine guiding me on what things I need to sort out first?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solve based on this article https://designsmaz.com/how-to-short-woocommerce-products-title/#comment-76957

Basically I just replace the `<?php the_title(); ?>` to

```
<?php 
$shorttitle = mb_substr(the_title('','',FALSE),0,45); 

echo $shorttitle; 
if (strlen($shorttitle) >44){ 
echo '&hellip;'; 

} 
?>
```